# Feature: User updates her email address

Tags: ruby, clearance

Is there a canonical way to build an “update email” feature on top of the Clearance gem?

To spell it out: I want a logged in users to be able to visit the site and update the email address associated with her account.

There’s lots of info about building a “change password” feature, but nothing about changing emails. I wanted to make sure I wasn’t missing anything before I invent a wheel.

Comment: I haven't seen such articles. Password is needed much more often, that's why you see more info about it. You'd be inventing the wheel here, not reinventing :)

Comment: Ooops, I meant "password __change__ is needed much more often". Noticed just now. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's not a canonical way, as far as I know. The simplest way to handle this, I think is to reset `current_user.confirmed_at` when the user changes their email address. Something like this should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :reset_confirmation_on_email_change

  private

  def reset_confirmation_on_email_change
    self.confirmed_at = nil if email_changed?
  end
end
```

The rest should be pretty straight forward like editing anything else. You might also want them to confirm their password when the email changes, this would look similar to requiring old password when the password is changed.

Comment: This seems reasonable. We actually aren't confirming email addresses at all at the moment, though. So it does not apply to my case.

Comment: @hoffm "aren't confirming email addresses" - then what is the question even? Just go ahead and update email, like any other field. :shrug:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Email addresses are used as log-in credentials, and also as recipients for transactional emails. We just don't confirm that you own the email address you give us (by sending you a confirmation email and requiring you to click through it).

Comment: @hoffm: yes, but none of this requires any more work (assuming you already have a unique index on email column in the db, as you should)

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the gem 'Devise'...very useful for user logins and updating passwords and emails. Makes creating a login page a breeze, along with logging users into the database.

Comment: I've used Devise. This app just happens to use Clearance.